# How to retrieve a resource Image stored in a Resource file added to the Project

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, resources

I'm trying to add an image to a ToolStrip. When trying to add the image, I get the error saying 'dog' is not a member of 'ToolStripEvents.My.Resources'.

I have added a new Resource File to my Visual Studio project and added the two existing images to the resource file. In the Solution Explorer, I see the Resources folder has the two images (dog.jpg and Euclid.jpg) in it.

In my Design for the form, I added the ToolStrip along with a Button. For the Button click event, I'm trying to add an image to the ToolStrip:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim atoolstripitem As ToolStripItem
        atoolstripitem = myToolStrip.Items.Add(My.Resources.dog)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Am I added the image resources correctly? If not, how can I add them correctly so I can use them in the ToolStrip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a Resource file to the Project, via `Project -> Add New Item -> Resource File`, you have to use the name you have assigned to this new Resource file, which is also assigned to the `internal` (`Friend`) class object that is created in the corresponding `[Resource].Designer.xx` file.
These Resource files are usually created in the root of the Project's folder structure (unless otherwise specified).

Assume the new Resource file has been named `ResourcesExtra`: you access its resource objects as `ResourcesExtra.SomeResourceName` (`ResourcesExtra.dog` here)

The OP is instead trying to access a resource image using `My.Resources`.
`My.Resources` points to the default Resource file associated with the Project, stored in the `My Project` folder in a VB.Net Project, or the `Properties` folder in a C# Project.
Of course, this Resource file doesn't hold a reference to the location of the Image stored in another Resource file, hence the exception.

Images added to Resource files are stored in the Project's `Resources` folder (VB.Net and C# Projects). Other types of resources in different locations (e.g., `\Obj\Debug` in case of files)

---

An extra Resource file is apparently not actually needed in this specific case, so moving the image to the Project's Resources is probably a good option (also removing the extra Resource file).
But using different Resource files for different *destinations* can be a good idea.
Also, you could extend the concept and move your Resources to a satellite assembly (a Library Project), used as storage for all the Resources need in a Project, adding static (Shared) methods to retrieve these objects, similar to what the [ResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager) does, but in a custom (specialized) manner.
Resources can be retrieved by name, index etc. and organized as required, e.g., to handle multiple languages.